# p-value for a vector in R

Tags: r, statistics

I want to get the p-value of a vector of F value in `R`.

```
set.seed(12345)
dat <- data.frame(df = round(runif(n=10, min=5, max=10)), F=runif(n=10, min=1, max=50))
pf(q = dat[2], df1 = dat[1], df2 = dat[10, 1], ncp = 0, lower.tail = FALSE, log.p = FALSE)
```

I can do this by element-wise but couldn't figure out how to accomplish this for a vector.

Comment: Had you used df[[2]] and df[[1]] you would have succeeded. The error message: "Non-numeric argument to mathematical function" is admittedly not very helpful, but maybe the next time you will remember to check if you have offered a list to an argument.expecting an atomic vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pf()` function works on vectors. Try:

```
pf(q = dat$F, df1 = dat$df, df2 = dat[10, 1], 
   ncp = 0, lower.tail = FALSE, log.p = FALSE)
```